# how to run CodePen project localy

Tags: javascript, html, codepen

i want to run a codePen project locally, but when i copy past the files into local project on my computer its not working, the project have 3 file(html,css,js(ts)).
how could i fix it and make it working?
the codepen project that i want to make it locally is below:
<kbd>https://codepen.io/mediapipe-preview/pen/OJBVQJm</kbd>

i copy pasted the files into local project but it seems the js file is not running, i even linked the js and css file into html file but its not working.
even i export the hole project from codepen but it still not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heya Hope you are doing well..here's a working version of the codepen you provided in local..i have made necessary changes for you..hope it will help you.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Face Landmarker</title>

  <style>
 

@use "@material";
body {
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 2em;
  color: #3d3d3d;
  --mdc-theme-primary: #007f8b;
  --mdc-theme-on-primary: #f1f3f4;
}

h1 {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #ff6f00;
  color: #007f8b;
}

h2 {
  clear: both;
}

em {
  font-weight: bold;
}

video {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

section {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
}

header,
footer {
  clear: both;
}

.removed {
  display: none;
}

.invisible {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.note {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 130%;
}

.videoView,
.detectOnClick,
.blend-shapes {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin: 2% 1%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.videoView p,
.detectOnClick p {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #007f8b;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
}

.highlighter {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25);
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.canvas {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.output_canvas {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.detectOnClick {
  z-index: 0;
}

.detectOnClick img {
  width: 100%;
}

.blend-shapes-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 20px;
}

.blend-shapes-label {
  display: flex;
  width: 120px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

.blend-shapes-value {
  display: flex;
  height: 16px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #007f8b;
}
  </style>

  <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Face landmark detection using the MediaPipe FaceLandmarker task</h1>

  <section id="demos" class="invisible">
    <h2>Demo: Detecting Images</h2>
    <p><b>Click on an image below</b> to see the key landmarks of the face.</p>

    <div class="detectOnClick">
      <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/mediapipe-assets/portrait.jpg" width="100%" crossorigin="anonymous" title="Click to get detection!" />
    </div>
    <div class="blend-shapes">
      <ul class="blend-shapes-list" id="image-blend-shapes"></ul>
    </div>

    <h2>Demo: Webcam continuous face landmarks detection</h2>
    <p>Hold your face in front of your webcam to get real-time face landmarker detection.</br>Click <b>enable webcam</b> below and grant access to the webcam if prompted.</p>

    <div id="liveView" class="videoView">
      <button id="webcamButton" class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised">
        <span class="mdc-button__ripple"></span>
        <span class="mdc-button__label">ENABLE WEBCAM</span>
      </button>
      <div style="position: relative;">
        <video id="webcam" style="position: abso" autoplay playsinline></video>
        <canvas class="output_canvas" id="output_canvas" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blend-shapes">
      <ul class="blend-shapes-list" id="video-blend-shapes"></ul>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script type="module">
   
import vision from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/tasks-vision@0.10.0";

const { FaceLandmarker, FilesetResolver, DrawingUtils } = vision;
const demosSection = document.getElementById("demos");
const imageBlendShapes = document.getElementById("image-blend-shapes");
const videoBlendShapes = document.getElementById("video-blend-shapes");

let faceLandmarker;
let runningMode= "IMAGE" | "VIDEO";
let enableWebcamButton = HTMLButtonElement;
let webcamRunning= Boolean = false;
const videoWidth = 480;

// Before we can use HandLandmarker class we must wait for it to finish
// loading. Machine Learning models can be large and take a moment to
// get everything needed to run.
async function runDemo() {
  // Read more `CopyWebpackPlugin`, copy wasm set from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/node_modules" to `/wasm`
  const filesetResolver = await FilesetResolver.forVisionTasks(
    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/tasks-vision@0.10.0/wasm"
  );
  faceLandmarker = await FaceLandmarker.createFromOptions(filesetResolver, {
    baseOptions: {
      modelAssetPath: `https://storage.googleapis.com/mediapipe-models/face_landmarker/face_landmarker/float16/1/face_landmarker.task`,
      delegate: "GPU"
    },
    outputFaceBlendshapes: true,
    runningMode,
    numFaces: 1
  });
  demosSection.classList.remove("invisible");
}
runDemo();

/********************************************************************
// Demo 1: Grab a bunch of images from the page and detection them
// upon click.
********************************************************************/

// In this demo, we have put all our clickable images in divs with the
// CSS class 'detectionOnClick'. Lets get all the elements that have
// this class.
const imageContainers = document.getElementsByClassName("detectOnClick");

// Now let's go through all of these and add a click event listener.
for (let i = 0; i < imageContainers.length; i++) {
  // Add event listener to the child element whichis the img element.
  imageContainers[i].children[0].addEventListener("click", handleClick);
}

// When an image is clicked, let's detect it and display results!
async function handleClick(event) {
  if (!faceLandmarker) {
    console.log("Wait for faceLandmarker to load before clicking!");
    return;
  }

  if (runningMode === "VIDEO") {
    runningMode = "IMAGE";
    await faceLandmarker.setOptions({ runningMode });
  }
  // Remove all landmarks drawed before
  const allCanvas = event.target.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("canvas");
  for (var i = allCanvas.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const n = allCanvas[i];
    n.parentNode.removeChild(n);
  }

  // We can call faceLandmarker.detect as many times as we like with
  // different image data each time. This returns a promise
  // which we wait to complete and then call a function to
  // print out the results of the prediction.
  const faceLandmarkerResult = faceLandmarker.detect(event.target);
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.setAttribute("class", "canvas");
  canvas.setAttribute("width", event.target.naturalWidth + "px");
  canvas.setAttribute("height", event.target.naturalHeight + "px");
  canvas.style.left = "0px";
  canvas.style.top = "0px";
  canvas.style.width = `${event.target.width}px`;
  canvas.style.height = `${event.target.height}px`;

  event.target.parentNode.appendChild(canvas);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const drawingUtils = new DrawingUtils(ctx);
  for (const landmarks of faceLandmarkerResult.faceLandmarks) {
    drawingUtils.drawConnectors(
      landmarks,
      FaceLandmarker.FACE_LANDMARKS_TESSELATION,
      { color: "#C0C0C070", lineWidth: 1 }
    );
    drawingUtils.drawConnectors(
      landmarks,
      FaceLandmarker.FACE_LANDMARKS_RIGHT_EYE,
      { color: "#FF3030" }
    );
    drawingUtils.drawConnectors(
      landmarks,
      FaceLandmarker.FACE_LANDMARKS_RIGHT_EYEBROW,
      { color: "#FF3030" }
    );
    drawingUtils.drawConnectors(
      landmarks,
      FaceLandmarker.FACE_LANDMARKS_LEFT_EYE,
      { color: "#30FF30" }
    );
    drawingUtils.drawConnectors(
      landmarks,
      FaceLandmarker.FACE_LANDMARKS_LEFT_EYEBROW,
      { color: "#30FF30" }
    );
    drawingUtils.drawConnectors(
      landmarks,
      FaceLandmarker.FACE_LANDMARKS_FACE_OVAL,
      { color: "#E0E0E0" }
    );
    drawingUtils.drawConnectors(landmarks, FaceLandmarker.FACE_LANDMARKS_LIPS, {
      color: "#E0E0E0"
    });
    drawingUtils.drawConnectors(
      landmarks,
      FaceLandmarker.FACE_LANDMARKS_RIGHT_IRIS,
      { color: "#FF3030" }
    );
    drawingUtils.drawConnectors(
      landmarks,
      FaceLandmarker.FACE_LANDMARKS_LEFT_IRIS,
      { color: "#30FF30" }
    );
  }
  drawBlendShapes(imageBlendShapes, faceLandmarkerResult.faceBlendshapes);
}

/********************************************************************
// Demo 2: Continuously grab image from webcam stream and detect it.
********************************************************************/

const video = document.getElementById("webcam");
const canvasElement = document.getElementById(
  "output_canvas"
);

const canvasCtx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");

// Check if webcam access is supported.
function hasGetUserMedia() {
  return !!(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia);
}

// If webcam supported, add event listener to button for when user
// wants to activate it.
if (hasGetUserMedia()) {
  enableWebcamButton = document.getElementById(
    "webcamButton"
  );
  enableWebcamButton.addEventListener("click", enableCam);
} else {
  console.warn("getUserMedia() is not supported by your browser");
}

// Enable the live webcam view and start detection.
function enableCam(event) {
  if (!faceLandmarker) {
    console.log("Wait! faceLandmarker not loaded yet.");
    return;
  }

  if (webcamRunning === true) {
    webcamRunning = false;
    enableWebcamButton.innerText = "ENABLE PREDICTIONS";
  } else {
    webcamRunning = true;
    enableWebcamButton.innerText = "DISABLE PREDICTIONS";
  }

  // getUsermedia parameters.
  const constraints = {
    video: true
  };

  // Activate the webcam stream.
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function (stream) {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.addEventListener("loadeddata", predictWebcam);
  });
}

let lastVideoTime = -1;
let results = undefined;
const drawingUtils = new DrawingUtils(canvasCtx);
async function predictWebcam() {
  const radio = video.videoHeight / video.videoWidth;
  video.style.width = videoWidth + "px";
  video.style.height = videoWidth * radio + "px";
  canvasElement.style.width = videoWidth + "px";
  canvasElement.style.height = videoWidth * radio + "px";
  canvasElement.width = video.videoWidth;
  canvasElement.height = video.videoHeight;
  // Now let's start detecting the stream.
  if (runningMode === "IMAGE") {
    runningMode = "VIDEO";
    await faceLandmarker.setOptions({ runningMode: runningMode });
  }
  let nowInMs = Date.now();
  if (lastVideoTime !== video.currentTime) {
    lastVideoTime = video.currentTime;
    results = faceLandmarker.detectForVideo(video, nowInMs);
  }
  if (results.faceLandmarks) {
    for (const landmarks of results.faceLandmarks) {
      drawingUtils.drawConnectors(
        landmarks,
        FaceLandmarker.FACE_LANDMARKS_TESSELATION,
        { color: "#C0C0C070", lineWidth: 1 }
      );
      drawingUtils.drawConnectors(
        landmarks,
        FaceLandmarker.FACE_LANDMARKS_RIGHT_EYE,
        { color: "#FF3030" }
      );
      drawingUtils.drawConnectors(
        landmarks,
        FaceLandmarker.FACE_LANDMARKS_RIGHT_EYEBROW,
        { color: "#FF3030" }
      );
      drawingUtils.drawConnectors(
        landmarks,
        FaceLandmarker.FACE_LANDMARKS_LEFT_EYE,
        { color: "#30FF30" }
      );
      drawingUtils.drawConnectors(
        landmarks,
        FaceLandmarker.FACE_LANDMARKS_LEFT_EYEBROW,
        { color: "#30FF30" }
      );
      drawingUtils.drawConnectors(
        landmarks,
        FaceLandmarker.FACE_LANDMARKS_FACE_OVAL,
        { color: "#E0E0E0" }
      );
      drawingUtils.drawConnectors(
        landmarks,
        FaceLandmarker.FACE_LANDMARKS_LIPS,
        { color: "#E0E0E0" }
      );
      drawingUtils.drawConnectors(
        landmarks,
        FaceLandmarker.FACE_LANDMARKS_RIGHT_IRIS,
        { color: "#FF3030" }
      );
      drawingUtils.drawConnectors(
        landmarks,
        FaceLandmarker.FACE_LANDMARKS_LEFT_IRIS,
        { color: "#30FF30" }
      );
    }
  }
  drawBlendShapes(videoBlendShapes, results.faceBlendshapes);

  // Call this function again to keep predicting when the browser is ready.
  if (webcamRunning === true) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(predictWebcam);
  }
}

function drawBlendShapes(el=HTMLCanvasElement, blendShapes= any[{}]) {
  if (!blendShapes.length) {
    return;
  }

  let htmlMaker = "";
  blendShapes[0].categories.map((shape) => {
    htmlMaker += `
      <li class="blend-shapes-item">
        <span class="blend-shapes-label">${
          shape.displayName || shape.categoryName
        }</span>
        <span class="blend-shapes-value" style="width: calc(${
          +shape.score * 100
        }% - 120px)">${(+shape.score).toFixed(4)}</span>
      </li>
    `;
  });

  el.innerHTML = htmlMaker;
}

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the photo section is completely works well, but i still have issue with the live camera, i means the camera will open and persons pictures show but it seems some part of the JS code is not working well because its not responsive the result like photo